# Multidimensional array with polymorphic relation (tree structure)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, recursion, tree

To understand what I want to do, here a simple expain : I want to create templates.

One "Template" has a "Panel"
This "Panel" has some "Item" and another "Panel"
We have to do this step by step until the last "Item"

I want something like this :

```
- Template
    - Panel "Section"
        - Panel "Slider"
            - Panel "Slide 1"
                - Item "Text 1"
                - Item "Text 2"
                - Item "Button"
            - Panel "Slide 2"
                - Panel "Buttons"
                    - Item "Button 1"
                    - Item "Button 2"
                - Item "Text"
```

With the polymorphic relations from Laravel, I have 3 Models which are "Panel", "Item" and "PanelContent" (this one has some attributesn "parent_id", "contentable_id and "contentable_type" usefull to know which Panel is the parent, and which Item or Panel will be the content.

Obvisouly, my Models contains some function usefull to get contents and parent.

#### What I did

Currently, I use a recursive function to get Panel's children to build step by step an array with the structure I shown at the beginning.

```php
private function getChildren(PanelContent $panelContent, string $parentName, string $key): void
{
    $this->result['template']['global_panel'][$parentName][$key] = $panelContent->contentable->toArray();
    if ($panelContent->contentable_type === 'panel') {
        foreach($panelContent->contentable->contents as $key => $container) {
            $this->getChildren($container, $container->contentable->name, $key);
        }
    }
}
```

#### What I want

I want to have something like this, like a tree structure.

```php
$this->result = [
    'template' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'MySlider'
        'contents' => [
            'id' => 745,
            'name' => 'slider',
            'type' => 'panel',
            'slides' => [
                0 => [
                    'id' => 500,
                    'name' => 'slide',
                    'type' => 'panel'
                    'buttons' => [
                        0 => [
                            'id' => 877,
                            'name' => 'button',
                            'type' => 'item'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                1 => [
                    'id' => 500,
                    'name' => 'slide',
                    'type' => 'panel'
                    'buttons' => [
                        0 => [
                            'id' => 877,
                            'name' => 'button',
                            'type' => 'item'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

#### What I have for the moment

Currently, I have something like this :

```php
$this->result = [
    'template' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'MySlider'
        'contents' => [
            'id' => 745,
            'name' => 'slider',
            'type' => 'panel'
        ],
        'slides' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 500,
                'name' => 'slide',
                'type' => 'panel'
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 500,
                'name' => 'slide',
                'type' => 'panel'
            ]
        ],
        'buttons' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 877,
                'name' => 'button',
                'type' => 'item'
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 877,
                'name' => 'button',
                'type' => 'item'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

With this code, the result is "normal", because the key at this line is wrong :

```php
$this->result['template']['global_panel'][$parentName][$key] = $panelContent->contentable->toArray();
```

But I really don't know how to do what I want with my data.
I hope my explains are fine. Do you have an idea about this ? How can I build properly my array (or json of course) ?

Thank you and have a nice day !

Comment: Why is `'global_panel'` absent from the "What I have for the moment" part when it's there as a key in your code? Solid question, btw!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Before to call my function for the first time, I have already begin to build my array with a template and his panel, this one is called 'global_panel'. I did it before because I know there is always only one template and only one 'global_panel'.

Comment: So the problem is that the buttons are not inside their slides. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. All my Panel/Item children are not inside their slides. I've just show with the buttons but I have the same problem with every children, like [this](https://i.ibb.co/D8zjZFL/array.png)

Comment: I'm a noob in Laravel, but you could iterate slides and move the button with the same key into the slide if everything fails. If you would like to have this unconventional solution, then please let me know.

Comment: I see. I'll continue to search the best solution but if I'll fail, I can try this. Thank you ! I'll tell you if I do it.

Comment: Np. If you resort to this, then please let me know. I will write an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Laravel has many helpers and there is one for array.

```
private function formatTemplateData(PanelContent $panelContent, string $path): void
{
    Arr::set(
        $this->result, 
        'template.data.' . $path, 
        "Je suis une data"
    );

    if ($panelContent->contentable_type === 'panel') {
        foreach($panelContent->contentable->contents as $container) {
            $newPath = $path . '.' . $container->contentable->name . $container->contentable->order;
            $this->formatTemplateData($container, $newPath);
        }
    }
}
```

With the "set" function, I can use string to create dynamic path for my array.
For example :

```
"template.data.slider.slide.0.test"
```

Will be :

```
$array['template']['data']['slider']['slide'][0]['test']
```

Thanks for your help.